# MVC Post form data using Ajax and GET

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, get

I have an MVC project inside this I hae form that post to a method (Create) inside a CommentController. I'm using httppost. The code goes like this:
The view that contains the form.

```
@model myproject.Models.Comment

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",
new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "CommentContainer" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserComment)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserComment)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserComment)
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Create comment" />
}

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

The CommentController contain the Create method

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Create(Comment comment)
{
    return PartialView("_RandomComment", comment);
}
```

Now all this is working fine, but what I want is to do it all using GET not POST. I still want to use the Ajax.BeginForm and the 2 javascript libraries. I do not want to write my own jQuery code. How do I post above form data to a GET method inside my CommentController.

Comment: Why do you want to POST data using a GET?

Comment: in order to avoid the post back warning when the user clicks the back button on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend sending form data using `GET`. However, if you really want to do it, just specify `"Get"` in the `AjaxOptions.HttpMethod` property.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", UpdateTargetId = "CommentContainer" }))
{
    ... your form elements ...
}
```

Also change your action method from accepting `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpGet]`.

Comment: Hi HTX9! Thanks for your suggestion, however this does not work. Its like the click event never get fired.

Comment: Wait! I tried some more and explicitly included the name of the controller (CommentController) which was not included in the POST version and know its working! Thanks! For the readers; The only thing changed in above code is the following: 1) @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comment",
                            new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", and inside the CommentController I just set [HttpGet] above the Create method.